# How to add lazy loading for mongoDB with fetching code being in +page.server.ts (server side)

Tags: mongodb, performance, sveltekit

So apparently I tried to making a happy birthday wish dashboard which included about 400 Document about (1mb), Which I tried ask ChatGPT before coming which give me no luck and trash answer for implementing lazy loading code for MongoDB with svelteKit on server side of code.

Which right now I tried with this code and it take about **10 second to page load** which is really long, (Mongodb free tier)

Can I have example of code or resource for I can implement code, Thanks!

This is +page.svelte

```
<!-- Content.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  
    export let data: PageData;
  
    let tutorials = data.tutorials;
    let isLoading = false;
    let page = 1;
  
    async function loadMore() {
      if (isLoading) return;
      isLoading = true;
  
      const response = await fetch(`/api/loadMore?page=${page + 1}`);
      const newData = await response.json();
  
      if (newData.length > 0) {
        page++;
        tutorials = [...tutorials, ...newData];
      }
  
      isLoading = false;
    }
  
    // Intersection Observer for infinite scrolling
    let sentinel;
  
    onMount(() => {
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        (entries) => {
          const entry = entries[0];
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            loadMore();
          }
        },
        { root: null, rootMargin: '0px', threshold: 0.1 }
      );
  
      observer.observe(sentinel);
    });
  
    function getCount(index) {
      return tutorials.length - index;
    }
  </script>
  
  
  <svelte:head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Svelte demo app" />
  </svelte:head>
  
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-5 my-auto">
    {#each tutorials as bwish, index}
        <div
            class="rounded-none justify-self-center flex-col relative overflow-hidden flex h-full w-full max-w-[425px] text-black/50"
            style="opacity: 1; transform: none; transition: opacity 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, transform 666ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;"
        >
            <svg
                preserveAspectRatio="none"
                version="1.2"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 402 49"
                class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-[300vh] object-fill -z-[1]"
                ><path
                    fill={bwish.gift.borderColor}
                    d="m0 24.5v24.5h13v-49h-13zm389 0v24.5h13v-49h-13z"
                /><path fill="#FFFFFF" d="m13 24.5v24.5h376v-49h-376z" /></svg
            ><svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 402 132" class=""
                ><path
                    fill={bwish.gift.borderColor}
                    d="m0 86v86h13v-159c304 0 313.3 0.1 311 1.7-1.4 0.9-4.3 2.2-6.5 2.8-2.8 0.7-4.4 1.9-5.3 3.8-1 2.3-0.9 3.1 0.5 5.5 0.9 1.5 1.8 5.2 2 8.2 0.2 3 1.1 7.8 2 10.5 1.3 3.6 3.6 7 8.8 12.2 5.5 5.7 7.6 7.3 10 7.3 1.6 0.1 3.5-0.5 4.2-1.2 0.6-0.8 4.8-1.6 10-2 4.8-0.4 11-1.5 13.8-2.4q5-1.8 10-6.9c2.7-2.8 6.9-7.1 9.3-9.6l4.3-4.4c-2.7-6.2-3.3-9.3-3.2-11 0.2-1.7-0.4-3.8-1.3-4.7-0.9-1-3-1.8-4.6-1.8-1.8 0-5.1-1.4-8.3-3.6-2.8-2-5.4-3.8-5.7-4-0.3-0.3 5.2-0.4 12.2-0.4h12.8v159h13v-172h-402z"
                /><path
                    fill="#FFFFFF"
                    d="m13 92.5v79.5h376v-159c-19.8 0-25.3 0.1-25 0.4 0.3 0.2 2.9 2 5.8 4 3.1 2.2 6.4 3.6 8.2 3.6 1.6 0 3.7 0.8 4.6 1.8 0.9 0.9 1.5 3 1.3 4.7-0.1 1.6 0.5 4.8 1.5 7l1.7 4c-6.7 6.9-10.8 11.2-13.6 14q-5 5.1-10 6.9c-2.7 0.9-9 2-13.8 2.4-5.2 0.4-9.4 1.2-10 2-0.7 0.7-2.6 1.3-4.2 1.2-2.4 0-4.5-1.6-10-7.3-5.2-5.2-7.5-8.6-8.8-12.2-0.9-2.8-1.8-7.5-2-10.5-0.2-3-1.1-6.7-2-8.3-1.4-2.3-1.5-3.1-0.4-5.4 0.8-1.9 2.4-3.1 5.2-3.8 2.2-0.6 5.1-1.9 6.5-2.8 2.3-1.6-7-1.7-154.3-1.7h-156.7z"
                /></svg
            >
            <div class="flex w-full flex-col px-4 py-2 absolute top-0 left-0">
                <div class="flex">
                    <img src={bwish.gift.imgURL} class="h-[80px] object-contain" /><b
                        class="text-[#4E4670] min-[425px]:text-[20px] text-[14px] overflow-hidden pt-4 min-[425px]:pr-20 min-[375px]:pr-16 pr-14"
                        >{bwish.name}</b
                    >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-1 h-full flex-col relative overflow-hidden px-4 py-2">
                <span
                    class="text-center text-[#4E4670] sm:text-xl overflow-hidden justify-center items-center flex flex-1"
                    >{bwish.comment}</span
                >
                <div class="w-full flex pt-4 min-[425px]:px-4 px-2 min-[425px]:text-base text-sm">
                    <span class="">{bwish.DMY}</span><span class="flex-1 text-right">{bwish.time}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 40 402 92"
                ><path
                    fill={bwish.gift.borderColor}
                    d="m0 66v66h402v-132h-13c0 57.5-0.1 60.1-1.8 60.9-1.1 0.7-3.2 0.5-6.2-0.6-2.5-0.8-7.4-1.5-11-1.6-5.4 0-7.5 0.5-12.5 3.1-3.3 1.7-7.5 3.6-9.3 4.4-1.9 0.7-3.6 2.3-4.1 3.8-0.5 1.4-0.5 3.3 0 4.3 0.6 1.1 0.4 3.4-0.5 6.5-0.8 2.6-1.7 6.3-2 8.2-0.4 1.9-0.7 6-0.7 9-0.1 3.4 0.7 7.6 2.1 11 1.2 3 2.8 6.2 3.6 7 0.7 0.8 1.4 1.8 1.4 2.3 0 0.4-64.6 0.7-143.5 0.7-78.9 0-143.5-0.2-143.5-0.5 0-0.3 0.6-1.1 1.3-1.7 0.6-0.7 2.3-1.9 3.7-2.6 1.4-0.7 3.4-2.6 4.5-4.2 1.1-1.6 3.3-3.7 5-4.7 1.7-0.9 3.8-2.5 4.8-3.5 0.9-1 1.7-2.7 1.7-3.8 0-1.1-1-3-2.2-4.3-1.3-1.2-3.2-4.5-4.2-7.2-1.1-2.8-3.1-6.8-4.6-9-1.5-2.2-4.5-5.2-6.6-6.7-2.2-1.5-4.5-2.8-5.2-2.8-0.6 0-2.9-1.2-4.9-2.7-2.1-1.5-4.9-2.6-6.3-2.6-1.4 0.1-3.6 1.3-5 2.6-1.4 1.4-4.3 3-6.5 3.7-2.2 0.7-5.8 2.3-8 3.4-2.2 1.2-5.7 3.2-7.7 4.6-2 1.4-4.6 4.1-5.7 6l-2.1 3.5v-86.5h-13z"
                /><path
                    fill="#FFFFFF"
                    d="m13 0h376v30c0 27.5-0.1 30.1-1.8 30.9-1.1 0.7-3.2 0.5-6.2-0.6-2.5-0.8-7.4-1.5-11-1.6-5.4 0-7.5 0.5-12.5 3.1-3.3 1.7-7.5 3.6-9.3 4.4-1.9 0.7-3.6 2.3-4.1 3.8-0.5 1.4-0.5 3.3 0 4.3 0.6 1.1 0.4 3.4-0.5 6.5-0.8 2.6-1.7 6.3-2 8.2-0.4 1.9-0.7 6-0.7 9-0.1 3.4 0.7 7.6 2.1 11 1.2 3 2.8 6.2 3.6 7 0.7 0.8 1.4 1.8 1.4 2.3 0 0.4-64.6 0.7-143.5 0.7-78.9 0-143.5-0.2-143.5-0.5 0-0.3 0.6-1.1 1.3-1.7 0.6-0.7 2.3-1.9 3.7-2.6 1.4-0.7 3.4-2.6 4.5-4.2 1.1-1.6 3.3-3.7 5-4.7 1.7-0.9 3.8-2.5 4.8-3.5 0.9-1 1.7-2.7 1.7-3.8 0-1.1-1-3-2.2-4.3-1.3-1.2-3.2-4.5-4.2-7.2-1.1-2.8-3.1-6.8-4.6-9-1.5-2.2-4.5-5.2-6.6-6.7-2.2-1.5-4.5-2.8-5.2-2.8-0.6 0-2.9-1.2-4.9-2.7-2.1-1.5-4.9-2.6-6.3-2.6-1.4 0.1-3.6 1.3-5 2.6-1.4 1.4-4.3 3-6.5 3.7-2.2 0.7-5.8 2.3-8 3.4-2.2 1.2-5.7 3.2-7.7 4.6-2 1.4-4.6 4.1-7.8 9.5zm375.3 110c0.4 0 0.7 2 0.7 9h-11l4.8-4.5c2.6-2.4 5.1-4.4 5.5-4.5zm-366 7c1 0 1.9 0.5 2.1 1 0.2 0.6-1.3 1-3.3 1-2.6 0-3.2-0.3-2.1-1 0.9-0.5 2.3-1 3.3-1z"
                /></svg
            >
            <div
                class=" absolute min-[425px]:bottom-0 -bottom-4 min-[425px]:right-14 right-10 -rotate-12 translate-x-[50%] z-[1] min-[425px]:scale-100 scale-[70%]"
            >
                <img class="w-24" src="favicon.png" />
                <div class="text-[#524973] absolute left-[36px] top-12 text-xl font-bold">
                    {getCount(index)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {#if index === tutorials.length - 1}
        <!-- Add the sentinel element for Intersection Observer -->
        <div bind:this={sentinel} class="sentinel" />
        {/if}
        {/each}
    
</div>

<style>
</style>
```

This is +page.server.svelte

```
import { bwish } from '$db/tutorials';
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';
import { start_mongo, close_mongo } from '$db/mongo';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async function () {
    await start_mongo().then(() => {
        console.log('Mongo started');
    });

    const data = await bwish
        .find(
            {},
            {
                projection: {
                    _id: 0,
                    name: 1,
                    comment: 1,
                    DMY: 1,
                    time: 1,
                    gift: {
                        id: null,
                        name: 1,
                        desc: 1,
                        imgURL: 1,
                        bgColorCode: 1,
                        borderColor: 1,
                        order: null
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        .toArray();

    console.log(data);
    close_mongo().then(() => {
        console.log('Mongo Closed');
    });

    return {
        tutorials: data
    };
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution! By using [SvelteKit Streaming with promises](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises)
And with [my code](https://github.com/siravijbb/Hoku-Birthday-2024-Wish-SendingAndReader/commit/20e9c3ac77f52ff44c2213a5a7f7a889fbba0f27) this make it very fast no more blocking

```
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';

export const load: PageServerLoad = () => {
    return {
        one: Promise.resolve(1),
        two: Promise.resolve(2),
        streamed: {
            three: new Promise((fulfil) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    fulfil(3);
                }, 1000);
            }),
        },
    };
};
```

By make not directly return object but next in return, sveltekit will automatically make it on premise
when print data at

```
const data = bwish
    .find(
        {},
        {
            projection: {
                _id: 0
            }
        }
    )
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .toArray();

console.log(data);
```

it will say `Promise { <pending> }` which mean it executed while it pending data will which we can integrate with

```
{#await data.fool.fool}
    Loading...
{:then value}
    {value}
{:catch error}
    {error.message}
{/await}
```

note data is returned value like
server code

```
return fool: { fool : data }
```

client code

```
let data = fool.fool?.tutorials ?? [];
```

also note: await in code might cause page to halt loading while await is not finished,so try don't use it.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: oh,sory for that let me fix it.